# Display a dictionary in a list box

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, listbox

I'm trying to display a dictionary in a list box in WPF but i get some errors and I can't figure it out. This is my list box:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstPrice" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="75" Margin="25.714,225,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190"/>
```

This is the dictionary which is defined in one of my classes:

```
   Dictionary<double, ProdType> prices = new Dictionary<double, ProdType>()
        {
            {5.4 , ProdType.Plain}; }
```

And here I tried to bind them in the loaded event of the window:

```
lstPrice.ItemsSource = new BindingSource(prices, null);
```

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'BindingSource' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error CS0103  The name 'prices' does not exist in the current context

There's an alternative for BindingSource in WTF ?
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try Prices as a public property

Comment: this.DataContext = this

Answer (score 0):

directly assign as `lstPrice.ItemsSource = prices`

then use `Value` property in Item template to bind the same.

Eg.

```
    <ListBox SelectedValuePath="Value">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795229/why-am-i-getting-a-the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-error-on-thi